# Map object array inside another object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I've got two arrays, one of which I want to map with another one as an object. For example :

```
var myArray = [{'id' : 'first', 'name' : 'firstname'}];
var addressArray = [{'city' : 'London', 'street' : 'Oxford'}];
```

I want to put `adress` array inside `myArray` as an object so that I have :

```
var newArray = [{'id' : 'first', 'name' : 'firstname', 'address' : {'city' : 'London', 'street' : 'Oxford'}}];
```

I have tried mapping with `forEach` method :

```
myArray.forEach(function(o, i){
    o.address = addressArray;
});
```

But I keep getting `[Object]` in my output :

```
[{'id' : 'first', 
  'name' : 'firstname', 
  'address' : [[Object], [Object]] }]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `index` to access the element

```
myArray.forEach(function(o, i){
    o.address = addressArray[i];
});
```

```js
var myArray = [{'id' : 'first', 'name' : 'firstname'}];
var addressArray = [{'city' : 'London', 'street' : 'Oxford'}];

myArray.forEach(function(o, i){
    o.address = addressArray[i];
});

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use map instead since it is actually a new array you are returning with modyfied items in it

```
var res = myArray.map((item, index) => {
  item.address = addressArray[index];
  return item;
});
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. this is a valid answer